# What is the general prescription for constructing the quantum mechanical momentum operator conjugate to a given coordinate?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, momentum, definition, commutator

Obviously, if $x$ is a Cartesian coordinate, then the corresponding momentum operator is $-i \hbar \partial_x$.  But what if $x$ is something more complicated, like some sort of curvilinear coordinate in 3D space?

There is this question elsewhere on this site.  [Quantum mechanical analogue of conjugate momentum](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/61678/) But it's not clear to me that the accepted answer there is really answering the question I am asking.  Nothing in the question or answer specifically addresses non-Cartesian coordinates, certainly not in any detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If an $n$-dimensional [configuration manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_space_(physics)) $M$ of some physical system is orientable and endowed with a positive volume form
$$\Omega~=~\rho(x)\mathrm{d}x^1\wedge\ldots\wedge\mathrm{d}x^n, \qquad \rho(x)~>~0,$$
we can define a [sesquilinear form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sesquilinear_form) 
$$\langle \phi | \psi\rangle~:=~\int_M \! \Omega ~\phi^{\ast} \psi. $$
The Schroedinger representation of the self-adjoint phase space operators is
$$ \hat{x}^j~=~x^j,\qquad  \hat{p}_k~=~\frac{\hbar}{i\sqrt{\rho(x)}} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^k} \sqrt{\rho(x)}, \qquad [\hat{x}^j,\hat{p}_k]~=~i\hbar\delta^j_k \mathbb{1}.  $$
See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/111216/2451) related Phys.SE post.